# Opening Different Tables in a Database

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have 3 different tables in a MySQL Database called "MyDB", the tables inside are table1, table2, table3.  Here is my code to query the 3 tables in the database but it keeps breaking and I can't figure out why.  Creating this for a Google Maps Javascript API v3.

```
private static IEnumerable<HeatMapDataElement> QueryHeatMapDataFromDatabase(string reqDate, string reportType)
    {
        const string connectionString = "connection_credentials";
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var elements = new List<HeatMapDataElement>();
        var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
            cmd.CommandText =
                "select RequestHour, longitude, latitude, count(requesttime) as Weight from MyDB.table1 || MyDB.table2 || MyDB.table3 where method=@ReportType and requestdate = date(@RequestDate) and longitude is not null and latitude is not null and requesthour is not null group by RequestHour, longitude, latitude";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportType", reportType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestDate", reqDate);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                elements.AddRange(from DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                                  select new HeatMapDataElement()
                                      {
                                          Latitude = Double.Parse(dr["latitude"].ToString()), Longitude = Double.Parse(dr["longitude"].ToString()), Hour = int.Parse(dr["RequestHour"].ToString()), Weight = int.Parse(dr["Weight"].ToString())
                                      });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex; //breaks here <-------
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            da = null;
            cmd = null;
        }
        return elements.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Error is:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|| MyDB.table2 where method='Table 2' and requestdate =' at line 1

Comment: " I can't figure out why" your compiler already did that for you. It even spelled it out for you in an error message. If you don't understand it, you need to post it here so we can explain it to you. I won't go through all that code again and repeat what your compiler already did way better than I could.

Comment: Does MySql support || as some kind of union shortcut operator? I have never seen that syntax. What makes you think it's correct SQL?

Comment: I figured that it was still C# since the file extension is .cs and || is 'or'

Comment: It's not C#, it's SQL. Read a good tutorial about SQL and how to concatenate tables. I'm not sure if you want a join or a union or something else entirely.

Comment: Ok thank you :D sorry if this was a poor question.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up C# code and SQL code. AFAIK pipe operator can only be used in mysql to join columns not tables, and even then, it's disabled by default, so I think that you need to use `INNER JOIN`

If you're reading from 3 tables you would do an inner join between the 3 tables, something like this:

```
 select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
```